# YouTube API seekTo plays only sound, no picture on second play on IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm building a website for my client who wants YouTube embedded video with external control. This is the code.

```
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        playerVars: {rel: 0},
        videoId: 'myvideoid',
        events: {
          'onReady': onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {          

          player.stopVideo();
        }

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $( '.play-btn' ).on( 'click', function() {

      if ($('.video').hasClass('mobile')) {

      }

      else {

        player.seekTo(0, true);
        player.playVideo();
      }

    });
```

This works fine on modern browsers, but on IE9 I have a problem: video starts playing when clicked. However, when video reaches it's end and I press external button again, I get "Error occurs" message and only video sound starts to play.

Any idea what might cause this?

EDIT

onError event gives error code 5, which is, as I've understood, HTML5 related. Error also occurs at the end of the video, not at the beginning, as I first thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing unnecessary stopVideo() function solved the problem. The video was already stopped at the end, when the function was called and apparently that caused the error.

This solved the problem in both IE9 and IE10.